# Why is my 'noremap % =' not taken into account?

Tags: vimrc, key-bindings

I use a completely remapped layout to match the traditional qwerty action position over a bépo layout.

Lately, using `NVIM v0.4.3`, my binding to map the `%` to `=` (format auto) ceased to work. This is very strange as all other binding seems to work fine, and actually if I run `noremap % =` at run time, everything comes back at the expected behaviour. Before manual intervention, a session will act like this:

```
:noremap %
o  %             <Plug>(MatchitOperationForward)                                                                                                                                              
x  %             <Plug>(MatchitVisualForward)                                                                                                                                                 
n  %             <Plug>(MatchitNormalForward)                                                                                                                                                 
s  %           * =
```

More information about my configuration

```
cat ~/.config/nvim/init.vim 
source ~/.config/vim/general

cat ~/.config/vim/general 
source ~/.config/vim/mapleader
source ~/.config/vim/paths
source ~/.config/vim/browse
source ~/.config/vim/indent-policy
source ~/.config/vim/rendering
source ~/.config/vim/save-policy
source ~/.config/vim/buffers
source ~/.config/vim/filetype
source ~/.config/vim/bépo

tail ~/.config/vim/bépo
noremap 4 $
noremap 5 %
noremap 6 ^
noremap 7 &
noremap 8 *
noremap 9 (
noremap 0 )
noremap ° _
noremap ` +
noremap % =
```

As you can see, as far as my custom configuration `noremap % =` is the last instruction and shouldn't be overwritten by something else as I don't have any `after/ftplugin` in my personal vim directories.

What am I missing?

Comment: You need to stop matchit from overriding your key-binds, since it comes later in the list of files vim sources when starting. More to follow.

Comment: It must be remembered that Neovim, unlike Vim, loads matchit plugin by default.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the tip, can you give me direct indication on how to either prevent the load of matchit, or defer my noremap after its load?

Comment: psychoslave, as usual, `let g:loaded_matchit = 1`

Comment: Ok, thank you @Matt what if I want to keep it enabled? I tried to `echo 'noremap % =' >~/.config/nvim/after/plugin/fix-bépo.vim` but it doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Oh, actually putting "let g:loaded_matchit = 1" before the bépo remapings works fine. Much thanks.

Comment: @Matt you can put your comment as an answer and I'll accept it as a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike Vim, Neovim by default loads `:h matchit` plugin. As plugins are normally loaded after vimrc, your mapping gets redefined inside matchit.

If you don't use matchit anyway, you can forbid it to load by adding `let g:loaded_matchit = 1` to your vimrc.

Comment: As I'm currently working on a Rails project, I guess Matchit might help me with `do … end` block, might not it? In that case, it seems that this solution fake that the Matchit plugin was loaded. Wouldn't be possible to also manually force the plugin loading?

Comment: Ok, with a `locate matchit.vim | xargs nvim`, I came to the conclusion that `:source /usr/share/nvim/runtime/pack/dist/opt/matchit/plugin/matchit.vim` what was I was looking for. But Matchit doesn't seem to come with Ruby support after all, or does it?

Comment: According to https://github.com/chrisbra/matchit the ex command `:packadd! matchit` should also do the trick.

Comment: @psychoslave By default, matchit functionality is available with remapped `%`. If you remap it yourself, you have to map its plugs to some other key in order to use it.

Comment: With a quick glance at matchit.vim, that would seem quite a large task to re-calibrate the whole thing, as it would probably require to dive deep in the code. I opened an issue on what seems to be the current canonical repository: https://github.com/chrisbra/matchit/issues/22

Comment: matchit maintainer here. So I guess, it would be preferable to only add the maps, if they have not been mapped yet, right?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Personally, I think it's enough to add support for `:h no_plugin_maps` and `no_matchit_maps`, as in a bunch of other standard plugins.

Comment: I think I have fixed it

Comment: Awesome, thanks @ChristianBrabandt I sent my additional remarks on the (closed) issue.